# merge xml childs with php

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

Been trying many different scripts and ended up with this one that I feel must be close to a solution, but not sure how to define the child. Tried "@name" and "name".
All the scripts I've tried is copied from here and there and modified for my use.

The XMLs have 1 node and 1 child each. Should not be much easier then this, but no luck.
Can mention that I also want the xsl stylesheet reference merged, but I think I just stumbeled over a solution for that, but forgot to bookmark the page.

xml 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<companyroutes>
  <route name="BBUPLOAD">ENGM OKSAT L996 SVD EKCH</route>

</companyroutes>
```

xml 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xml" href="merge2.xsl"?> 
<companyroutes>
   <route name="XXXXCORE">RUTA TULLA L666 BARE LITT MNOP</route>

</companyroutes>
```

And the PHP code (this file resides in the same dir as the output file:

```
  <?php
    $doc1 = new DOMDocument();
    $doc1->load('/uploads/companyroutes.xml');

    $doc2 = new DOMDocument();
    $doc2->load('/uploads/companyroutes_core.xml');

    // get 'res' element of document 1
    $res1 = $doc1->getElementsByTagName('res')->name(0);

    // iterate over '@name' elements of document 2
    $companyroutes2 = $doc2->getElementsByTagName('name');
    for ($i = 0; $i < $companyroutes2->length; $i ++) {
        $name2 = $companyroutes2->name($i);

        // import/copy @name from document 2 to document 1
        $name1 = $doc1->importNode($name2, true);

        // append imported @name to document 1 'res' element
        $res1->appendChild($name1);

    }
    $doc1->save('companyroutes.xml'); 
    ?>
```

Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to merge the files with `simplexml`:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x1); // assume XML in $x1 and $x2
$xml2 = simplexml_load_string($x2);

foreach ($xml2->route as $route) {  // merge $xml2 into $xml
    $newroute = $xml->addChild("route", $route);
    $newroute->addAttribute("name", $route['name']);
}

unset($xml2); // dispose $xml2

echo $xml->asXML();
```

see it working: https://eval.in/97372

Comment: Will $x1 and $x2 be URLs to the two xml files? Like:

$x1 = ('/uploads/companyroutes.xml');

Comment: @NAX in my example, they are strings. Look at the link in my answer. You can use simplexml_load_file with the filenames instead.

Comment: So I simply change the first two lines with: $xml = simplexml_load_file('/uploads/companyroutes_core.xml'); ... and $xml2 = simplexml_load_file('/uploads/companyroutes.xml')
...  Can I add a line after the echo command so that the script copies the result xml and paste to Companyroutes_core.xml? I need this function to ensure the result xml is the core for the next merge. The /uploads/companyroutes.xml is uploaded by many users adding their new entries to the merged file. If the core is not updated, new entries will be lost when the next person upload and merge. file_put maybe?

Comment: @NAX `$xml2` is merged into `$xml`, so this should be your target file. The `echo` in my code is just for demonstration purposes, read the **simplexml manual on php.net** on how to save XML to file.

Answer (score 1):

Two steps, prepare the target DOM (add the document element). Load each source XML, traverse the child nodes inside the document element and import them into your target document:

```
$xmlFiles = [
  '/uploads/companyroutes.xml',
  '/uploads/companyroutes_core.xml'
];

$targetDom = new DOMDocument();
$targetDom->appendChild(
  $targetDom->createProcessingInstruction(
    'xml-stylesheet', 'type="text/xml" href="merge2.xsl"' 
  )
);
$rootNode = $targetDom->appendChild(
  $targetDom->createElement('companyroutes')
);

foreach ($xmlFiles as $xmlFile) {
  $importDom = new DOMDocument();
  $importDom->load($xmlFile);
  foreach ($importDom->documentElement->childNodes as $node) {
    $rootNode->appendChild($targetDom->importNode($node, TRUE));
  }
}

echo $targetDom->saveXml();
```

An example with XML strings as sources: https://eval.in/97405

Of course you could create a template XML for the target DOM and just load it:

```
$template = <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xml" href="merge2.xsl"?> 
<companyroutes/>
XML;

$targetDom = new DOMDocument();
$targetDom->loadXml($template);
$rootNode = $targetDom->documentElement;
...
```

I would not suggest changing a document. If you build a new document you can repeat the action.

Comment: I can relate to the first script here, as I kinda understand all lines. I will test this one later today.

Comment: The second example just shows an alternative to create the $targetDom and assign the $rootNode variable by loading a template xml.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I did a little edit and got it running.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('./uploads/companyroutes_core.xml');  // xml files URL insted of $x
$xml2 = simplexml_load_file('./uploads/companyroutes.xml');

foreach ($xml2->route as $route) {  // merge $xml2 into $xml
    $newroute = $xml->addChild("route", $route);
    $newroute->addAttribute("name", $route['name']);
}

unset($xml2); // dispose $xml2

$xml->asXML('merged.xml'); //this line saves to directory and name of choice
```

My only problem now is that all Childs is output on one single line. A 4Mb long line. Need it to be more tidy (yes I've read about tidy commands, but how to use it here...? idunno) and breake it up for each child. Thanks for the patience so far. Don't be suppriced if you see me asking more basic questions, but the good thing is that I learn more each day I struggle with it.

Comment: @michi Is it possible to insert command for only merging unique entries? I found exemple using array and only merging unique childs, but cannot directly insert those lines into this script. Could the function of this script be done by using arrays?